# How to protect RFID data from cloning?

Tags: embedded, iot, rfid

I am working on the RFID-RC522 module security.I have searched some theoratical solutions of RFID security like:
Mutual authentification
Basic access control
Password lock etc to secure my RFID data from unidentified reader.
How can I program a tag that can check a value coming from reader and match it with the value stored into tag, only if the data is matched than the tag will send the data to the
reader.
**Note: I don't want to write anything from the reader site**